# Datatables ajax post request fails with status code 500

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, http-error

The following post request is failing with HTTP error 500 but I can't see why.

The request looks like this:

```js
var table = table = $('#table-styling').DataTable({
  serverSide: true,
  pageLength: 25,
  processing: true,
  language: {
      loadingRecords: "Loading...",
      processing: "Loading..."
  },
  ajax: {
      url: '/myapplication/myrequest',
      type: 'POST',
      contentType: "application/json;",
      dataType: 'json',
      traditional: true,
      data: function (d) {
          return JSON.stringify(d);
      },
      headers: {
          AntiForgeryToken: $(':input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
      }
  },

// etc.
```

The request header looks like this:

```
Request URL: https://myapplication.com/myrequest
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 
Remote Address: 1.1.1.1:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
date: Fri, 15 May 2020 14:38:22 GMT
server: Kestrel
status: 500
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
:authority: myapplication.com
:method: POST
:path: myapplication/myrequest
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
antiforgerytoken: xxx
content-length: 1600
content-type: application/json;
cookie: xxx
origin: https://myapplication.com
referer: https://myapplication.com/myrequest
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
```

This is an ASP.Net MVC app, my controller returns the view, which fires this post request off like so:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            myscript.function.load();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: An http error 500 it's a problem on the server.

Comment: i'm using ASP.net MVC and all my controller does is return a view that calls this post script. i'll clarify in my question.

Comment: I think there is an error on the c# server side in the action "/myapplication/myrequest"

Comment: it's not possible as I have a breakpoint in the controller that is never getting hit.

Comment: @NathanBruet yeah ok it was a server side problem :) but my issue was that Visual Studio did NOT hit my breakpoint unless I started my ASP.Net application with IIS Express. When I switched to IIS, the breakpoint was hit and I could debug the real issue with turned out to be a bug with recently changed data.

My first idea was to breakpoint the controller but as that wasn't being hit, I guessed the issue happened before. Confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, as the HTTP error code suggested, a server side issue.

So naturally I put a breakpoint in my controller but the breakpoint wasn't hit while debugging.

What I needed to do was launch my web app with IIS Express, only then did the breakpoint get hit and I was able to debug the real server side issue.